# Parse error in CoffeeScript + Backbone save function

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to use CoffeeScript with Backbone.js (via Brunch) and I want to implement a save function in my model, but it refuses to compile and I have been unable to figure out why. I need to both pass parameters into the save function and implement callbacks.

The code below gives an `Unexpected ':'` error on the second line, but I'm not sure why:

```
class exports.Tag extends Backbone.model

  defaults:
    id: null
    tagId: null
    found: false
    location: "Not yet found..."
    finders: []
    pointValue: 0
    unlockCode: ""

  verifyCode = ( code ) ->
    @save { tagId: @get 'tagId', unlockCode: code },
      success: ( model, response ) ->
        @trigger 'verifySuccessful', response
      error: ( model, response ) ->
        @trigger 'verifyFailed', response
```

Any help appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's here, you are confusing the parser

```
@save { tagId: @get 'tagId', unlockCode: code },
```

Is that this?

```
@save { tagId: @get('tagId'), unlockCode: code },
```

Or this?

```
@save { tagId: @get('tagId', unlockCode: code) },
```

Either will fix the error, but they obviously mean different things.

And might I add, implicit parens are indeed awesome, but take advantage of that awesome only in the most simple of circumstances.  A rule I usually use is that omit parens for the first function invocation in a line, and use them for all others.  This rule would have saved you from this issue entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the help @alex. Being very new to CoffeeScript, I'm still not really versed in the syntax and when parentheses are necessary, implicit, or error-causing. Thanks again!